# Using Laravel firstOrCreate function to search in two columns

Tags: laravel

how can I check two columns with firstOrCreate function? I need to work this like `where('email', $request->email)->orWhere('personal_code', $request->personal_code)`, not like `where('email', $request->email)->where('personal_code', $request->personal_code)`

```
$user = User::firstOrCreate(
    [
        'email'         => $request->email,
        'personal_code' => $request->personal_code,
    ],
    [
        'name'      => $request->tenant,
        'phone'     => $request->phone,
        'address'   => $request->address
    ]
);
```

Thanks for help in advance!

Comment: You won't be able to do an `or` using the `firstOrCreate()` method. Do you just want code to solve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You won't be able to run an `or` within the `firstOrCreate()` method.

To achieve this, you would need to create using custom functionality:

```
$user = User::where('email', $request->email)
    ->orWhere('personal_code', $request->personal_code);

$user = $user->exists()
    ? $user->first()
    : User::create($request->only(['email', 'personal_code', 'name', 'phone', 'address']));


// or $request->expect('_token') if all data passed via form.
```